# Splash doesn't get entire page

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I first run splash on a docker using:

```
docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash
```

When I go to port 8050 and try to render:
 http://warframe.market/

It doesn't render the body. More specifically between `<section id="warframe_react"><section>`

I tried using verbose mode, longer wait times, but it doesn't seem to get it. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it. You need to disable private mode **before** you render the page in splash (-_-')